# xcode becomes unresponsive when opening react-native init file

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-cli

whenever I try to open app created with react-native with xcode, xcode becomes unresponsive. I tried to download xcode-beta and try, and create a new react-native init in other places, but whenever I open them, xcode becomes unresponsive and blanks out..

Comment: Did you try to use react-native run-ios if yes, then what happens with this command is this run your app or give some error if no try this command and comment here what happens when you run this command.
First confirms that is there any issue with your IOS directory code or with your Xcode.

Comment: everything was working fine until recently and suddenly my xcode is just getting unresponsive.. This happens for all of my react-native projects, including the ones that I have worked on previously.

Comment: this is happening for all of my projects that were created with react native. However, the ones that were created on xcode work fine

Comment: did you try to delete derived data?

Comment: it was a problem with icloud drive

Comment: Ahhh! you resolved it?

Comment: yes there was a problem going on with synchronization with icloud drive. Fixed it by removing icloud from desktop

Comment: great! good to know.